# Use same keyEquivalent in NSPopupButton menu as in Main menu

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I have an `NSPopUpButton` that has a few menu items that expose identical functionality to some main menu items. Those are actions most relevant to the users current context.

To signal that those items also have `keyEquivalent`s (shortcuts), I wanted to set their `keyEquivalent`s to the same keys as the items in the main menu.

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, since the conflicting items now have their `keyEquivalent`s removed in the main menu (presumably automatically by AppKit).

Is it somehow possible to show the same `keyEquivalent` in the `NSPopUpButton` menu?

Comment: Weird, I tried this with Command-X, C and V and the key equivalents in the Xcode Edit menu are also removed.

Comment: The `NSPopUpButton` is in pull-down mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally context menus are not the most logical place to show shortcut info. However, if you really want this, then the best / probably only working option is to reuse the menu in the main menu that you want to show in your `NSPopUpButton`, like this:

```
myPopUpButton.menu = (NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).myMenu
```

In this example, `myMenu` is an `@IBOutlet` to one of the `NSMenu` items of the application main menu.

If you want to show a slightly different menu in your popup, then you can implement `menuWillOpen` of the `NSMenuDelegate` to dynamically hide or add menu items.

Comment: I was afraid that I might have to use the same `NSMenu` instance to make it work - so it probably is the only feasible solution. But I don't think it would be worth the trouble thought.